# How to get a collection inside a document on Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've a collection called `users`, inside each document's users have a collection called `monthlies` and I want get it. 
This is the structure:

[image]

At now, I tried get it using:

```
var getUsers = async function() {
        var db = firebase.firestore()
        var users = await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .get();
        return users
}

var getMonthlyByUserId = async function () {
    var users = await getUsers()
    users.forEach(element => {
        var monthlies = element.collection('monthlies').get()
        console.log(monthlies.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    })
}
```

But it prints nothing. The goal is iterate of all documents' monthlies of the collection.

Comment: `getUsers()` returns collection, loop through each document inside that collection first, then loop through each `monthlies` collection inside each document.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `element` is a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) type object.  It doesn't have a method called `collection()`, so I would expect your code will crash with an error in the log.

If you want to reference a subcollection organized under a document represented by QueryDocumentSnapshot, you should build upon its [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#ref) property:

```
users.forEach(snapshot => {
    var monthlies = snapshot.ref.collection('monthlies').get()
    console.log(monthlies.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
})
```

Alternatively, if you just want to query all documents in all subcollections called "monthly", you can simplify that with a single [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the problem that Doug pointed out (you need to use the `ref` property of the `QueryDocumentSnapshot`), you need to take into account that the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method is asynchronous.

So doing

```
users.forEach(snapshot => {
    var monthlies = snapshot.ref.collection('monthlies').get()
    console.log(monthlies.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
})
```

will not work.

If you cannot use a collection group query (for example, let's imagine that your `getUsers()` function only returns a subset of all the users, e.g. all users of a given country) you could use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
var getMonthlyByUserId = async function () {
    const users = await getUsers();
    const promises = [];
    users.forEach(snapshot => {
      promises.push(snapshot.ref.collection('monthlies').get());
    });
    const monthlies = await Promise.all(promises);
    monthlies.forEach(snapshotArray => {
      console.log(snapshotArray.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    });
 }
```

**OR** you could use the technique described in this [article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) on how to use async/await inside a `forEach()`.